# JarClassLoader - loading jars dynamically - how to?

Tags: java, classloader

I have seen many class loader questions, but still was not able to figure why, the error here.

I am writing a program which uses 2 versions of jars. One is needed to get content from older storage, and another to store content in new storage.

Since, I need either of the jar to be loaded at a time, I used JarClassLoader to create a proxy for adding one jar and loading its classes. But I face ClassNotFoundException.

```
public class HbaseMigrator  implements Runnable {
   public void run() {
     JarClassLoader jcl = new JarClassLoader();
     jcl.add("hadoop-0.13.0-core-modified-1.jar");
     Object obj1 = JclObjectFactory.getInstance().create(jcl, "UserMigThreadImpl", toProcessQueue,threadName, latch,DBUtil,lock);
     MigThread mig = JclUtils.cast(obj1, MigThread.class, jcl);
     Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(jcl);
     try {
         Method method = MigThread.class.getMethod("callthis", new Class[]{});
         method.invoke(mig, new Object[]{});
        // mig.callthis();
     } catch( Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     } catch(Error er) {
         er.printStackTrace();
     }
  }
}
```

Method called is:

```
 public void callthis() {
    DFSUtil = new DFSAccessAPIImpl();
    .........
 }
```

This class instantiation internally uses **hadoop** modified jar, which is not picked up from my classloader and it throws `ClassNotFoundException`.

What is that I am doing wrong ?

> JarClassLoader used here is jcloader :
>   org.xeustechnologies.jcl.JarClassLoader

Comment: Check the ClassLoader used :  Class.getClassLoader() at different point and différent class to valide that it your classLoader that is used.

Comment: @Mr_Thorynque : UserMigThreadImpl.class.getClassLoader() shows original parent classloader and its classes, and not the new classloader which I just created. How to resolve this ?

Comment: To resolve this kind of issue OSGI was created. So the right solution is to run in an OSGI container... I know that solution is probably not realistic for you.

Comment: Why you set your new jcl in  currentThread after create UserMigThreadImpl object ? And why don't use basic java.lang.ClassLoader ?

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this problem with loading plugins to my application, so I decided to try to load all .class files from all jars in path. Maybe this code snipped from my app will help you.

https://bitbucket.org/rsohlich/plagdetector/src/432b52f252ff7647221b7e91b08731bd9cbe2a70/PlagDetectorSpring/src/main/java/cz/sohlich/app/service/impl/PluginHolderImpl.java

Comment: Thanks @RadekSohlich. But I have 2 versions of jar which have conflicts. So i should not load all the jars here right ?

Comment: Well we have been experimenting with this and most of our fails were connected with obtaining/using bad ClassLoader. (different for application server, different for standalone jar). Now my idea here is to use URLClassLoader ucl = URLClassLoader.newInstance(urls, Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()); where the reference for current thread is. Not sure if Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(jcl); works corectly. In the experiments we were hot swapping jars and it just worked, the classloader always replaced the old one with the new one.