# Java ClassLoader - NoClassDefFoundError from missing dependency

Tags: java, eclipse, classloader

I'm trying to load a class at runtime using the classloader. The code looks roughly so:

```
URLClassLoader jarClassLoader =  new URLClassLoader(new URL[] { myIFile.getLocationURI().toURL() }); //myFile is a jar packaging required librairies
Class<? extends RTTestCase> testCaseClass = (Class<? extends RTTestCase>)jarClassLoader.loadClass("com.myPackagePath." + testCaseClassName);
RTTestCase myTestCase = testCaseClass.newInstance(); //java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/core/resources/IProject
jarClassLoader.close();
```

So it seems the IProject class is not found by jarClassLoader. I did export my class as jar with the "export libraries" option in Eclipse, so the JAR containing this class (some eclipse library) is available in the exported JAR as well as in the system path.

So what am I missing here? Is it a setup problem where the exported JAR is not properly packed, or do I need to load IProjects and all other dependencies manually first? How to do that ?

Background:
I am building an application which is started from an Eclipse environment. This application finds other projects from the current workspace and from each project executes a big program that might crash in difficult-to-analyze ways if the project content is not correct or if the big program itself has bugs.
  Before executing the big program I want to copy and modify the Eclipse project in various ways, to "transform" it. So I want to have the possibility to separate these transformation rules from my application itself, by letting my colleagues simply implement classes inheriting from RTTestCase, code whatever they want to do on the project, pack it in a jar and then the application finds it, load the main class from the jar (standardized naming) and can execute the transformation by passing the current project to the class and running a main function.
Other solutions, such as starting the jar from a command line are not optimal, since the project would probably have to be loaded again and we're talking about gigabyte-big projets (and numerous executions). Furthermore loading the transformation rule from the application would allow the transformer to provide a configuration GUI for example, or a evaluation hook called again directly from the current execution thread.

Comment: Just a wild guess: Try to set the contextClassLoader of the current Thread to your jarClassLoader before calling newInstance(), and reset it afterwards. `Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(jarClassLoader);`

Comment: Sadly it doesn't help. I wonder if the URLClassLoader searches for .class files but doesn't bother with packed jar files (I can't use JarClassLoader because of java versions)... There's a post that might help me (https://stackoverflow.com/a/31532756/131679).

Comment: Are these Eclipse plugins you are trying to use? Eclipse has a very elaborate class loader system and you can't just use URLClassLoader to access plugin classes.

Comment: Hello greg-449, I have edited my post to add background information.

Comment: Eclipse plugins such as the one you seem to be trying to load from rely on the Eclipse/OSGi system to deal with the plugin dependencies listed in the MANIFEST.MF Require-Bundle, Import-Package, and Bundle-Classpath statements.Reproducing this outside of Eclipse (or some other OSGi container) is a lot of work.

Answer (score 1):

I think I have a solution - partially at least... By instantiating the ClassLoader this way:

```
URLClassLoader urlClassLoader = new URLClassLoader(new URL[] { testCaseFile.getLocationURI().toURL() }, Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader());
```

Which gives the current thread ClassLoader (i.e. my application's ClassLoader) as parent of the new ClassLoader. So it seems that when the loaded class tries to use a class, it is first searched in the parent ClassLoader, which has access to the entire Eclipse environment (since my application is started from Eclipse).

I'm saying "partially" because I might have problems if I try to execute the application outside of Eclipse, although it should be possible to pass the eclipse classpaths as argument. Also I have only performed minimal testing (hello wolrd).

---

Update:
It worked... until I decided to instantiate new class from my loaded class, for example:

```
Class<? extends ParentClass> myClassA = urlClassLoader.loadClass(pathA);
Class<? extends ParentClass> myClassB = urlClassLoader.loadClass(pathB);

ParentClass myA = myClassA.newInstance(); //OK
ParentClass myB = myClassB.newInstance(); //OK
myA.methodThatInstantiatesClassB(); // NOK -> ClassDefNotFoundException
```

I guess the main thread Classloader is not inherited further by the dynamically loaded and instantiated classes... So I started searching about how to pass the ClassLoader, or change the system ClassLoader, before I eventually notice that since I'm starting my tool from Eclipse, I can set all my additional JARs as libraries for the project from which I start my tool, so that the JARs are in the system ClassLoader (I still need to find the < ? extends ParentClass> dynamically, but then I don't have to worry about their dependencies, as everything is in their JARs).

I do this statically (configure build path in project), but I suppose it would also be possible to search the JARs in a folder and add them to the System Classpath at start (ANT script for example).

---

In short:

- Add JARS to classpath when starting the program, either over Eclispse configuration or via ANT/command line
- Dynamically load the "main" class (which extends an abstract parent class known by the program) and use them normally after that.

Comment: Eclipse doesn't have just one classpath. Every plugin has its own individual classpath with separate class loaders. So I think you will still hit problems with missing plugins, incorrect plugins....